# volterra integral

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-equations

[image]

Good day, I'm studying about Volterra integral. What justifies the last 2 inequalities? If I am not wrong, the norm is the $\sup$-norm on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

First one is simply bringing in the absolute value inside the integral and using the previous result. Second one is using Mean Value theorem for $F(u)$.

Comment: In the second, Is analogous to making the area rectangle (b-a) M with M the maximum?

Comment: I confuse me when interpret it geometrically